# how to create ProcSet - pdfbox. (Procedure Sets)

Tags: pdf, adobe, digital-signature, pdfbox

I'm building pdf file using pdfbox.

now, I want to create ProcSet with some values. how to create that?

I mean, How to add  COSArray to  PDResources;

I have PDResources  and want to add here:

```
PDResources iRes = new PDResources();
```

I want something like that:
[image]

thank you.

Comment: I get getCOSDictionary from all the PDResources. and then setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, array);

Comment: Note the PDF norm: "Beginning with PDF 1.4, this feature is considered obsolete. For compatibility with existing conforming readers, conforming writers should continue to specify procedure sets (preferably, all of those listed in Table 314 unless
it is known that fewer are needed). However, conforming readers should not depend on the correctness of this information."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve, lLike that:

```
COSArray defaultRes = new COSArray();
            defaultRes.add(COSName.getPDFName("PDF"));
            defaultRes.add(COSName.getPDFName("Text"));
            defaultRes.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageB"));
            defaultRes.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageC"));
            defaultRes.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageI"));
```

and then:

```
     resources.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET,defaultRes);
```

resource is reference variable of PDResources.